# Custom Clearence Detail and PuposeOf Shipment Type Object in Fedex Web Services

Tags: web-services, c#-4.0, web, fedex

I am Trying To Use Fedex Web Service For Getting their  For Services From an  Indian Address To Indian Address. But Iam Not Getting A Right Reply Object in Get Fedex Rate Function 
Error that I Am  Getting is ......Object Refencence Can Not Be Null

They Are Showing Two Objects Their.One Is CustomclearenceDetail and Other Is Purpose Of ShipmentType.
my SetShipmentDetails Function Is Like This..

```
private  void SetShipmentDetails(RateRequest request)
{
    request.RequestedShipment = new RequestedShipment();
    request.RequestedShipment.PackagingType = PackagingType.YOUR_PACKAGING;
    request.RequestedShipment.PackagingTypeSpecified = true;
    request.RequestedShipment.DropoffType = DropoffType.REGULAR_PICKUP;
    request.RequestedShipment.DropoffTypeSpecified = true;
    request.RequestedShipment.CustomsClearanceDetail.CommercialInvoice.TaxesOrMiscellaneousChargeType = TaxesOrMiscellaneousChargeType.TAXES;

    SetOrigin(request);
    SetDestination(request);
    SetPackageLineItems(request);

    request.RequestedShipment.RateRequestTypes = new RateRequestType[2];
    request.RequestedShipment.RateRequestTypes[0] = RateRequestType.PREFERRED;
    request.RequestedShipment.RateRequestTypes[1] = RateRequestType.LIST;
    request.RequestedShipment.PackageCount = "1";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There Was A Proble That I Was Not Creating A New Instance Of Objects I Want To Use Here..By Creating A New Instance This Problem Will Be Solved.